# Spring one to one relationship

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, one-to-one

I have a very simple question. I don't know if I didn't understand something or if I don't know how to do it.
I have been wondering for a long time how one-to-one in hibernate spring. I can get to the table in two directions.
Let's say I have Hotel and hotelDetails tables.
A key is being created for me so that I can get to hotelRating from the hotel, but I can't go the other way.
Sometimes it is important to me.
I will use the sample code.

```java
public class Hotel {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String currency;
    private String image;
    private HotelRating hotelRating;


    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
.
    .
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "hotel_rating_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    public HotelRating getHotelRating() {
        return hotelRating;
    }

    public void setHotelRating(HotelRating hotelRating) {
        this.hotelRating = hotelRating;
    }
```

Hotel Rating table.

The problem is , when I am trying to allow to make getter and setter do hotel . I have getting :

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.flightradar.flightradar.model.hotel.Hotel, at table: hotel_rating, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(hotel)]

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "hotel_rating")
public class HotelRating {

    private long id;

    private Integer votesNumber;

    @Min(1)
    @Max(5)
    private Double average;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "hotel_rating")
    Hotel hotel;



    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getVotesNumber() {
        return votesNumber;
    }

    public void setVotesNumber(Integer votesNumber) {
        this.votesNumber = votesNumber;
    }

    public Double getAverage() {
        return average;
    }

    public void setAverage(Double average) {
        this.average = average;
    }

}
```

So, guys help me understand the easiest possibility to get to Hotel table from HotelRating Table.
For example I have HotelRating list and I have to get from Hotel table for each hotelRanking object.

Comment: Is there a Java property called `hotel_rating` with type `HotelRating` in the class `Hotel`? The exception indicates that this is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "mappedBy" value in class `HotelRating` has to provide

> The field that owns the relationship.

In your example the value is "hotel_rating"

```
 @OneToOne(mappedBy = "hotel_rating")
 Hotel hotel;
```

but there is no such field in class `Hotel`. The corresponding field might be "hotelRating".

Comment: Ohh Thank You :D It was so simple!